# PHP: Get all valid domains and ip addresses from the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

So far I have used the preg_match_all function with various expressions, but I am not good at regex.

I have a string (downloaded html page). Of course, there are a lot of things on it. Including assets. I need to extract all valid domains and IPv4 addresses from this string.

If it is possible from a regular expression: I would also like to remove the rest of the address and query. However, if this is not possible, I can remove it in later processing.

This expression for domains works quite well, although it could be better, because it also catches garbage like "/html/style/global.css.php". And does not work on IP addresses

```php
preg_match_all('#[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]*)?#si', $response->body(), $match);
```

Comment: "I need" is not a question. Please show what you tried and we'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you. Try googling "domain name regular expression"

Comment: I added my current expression

Comment: Why `{2,256}`? `x.com` is a valid domain.

Comment: You have lots of characters that aren't allowed in domain names. They can only be letters, digits, `-` and `.`. Not `@`, `~`, `&`, etc.

Comment: It is not possible to extract domains from free form text as the boundary's are always undefined, and cannot be within free form text. You can make attempt's using expert coded regex, but cannot resolve boundary's. Unless artificially imposed, which is not guaranteed to match or match correctly let alone validity. I would say there is a 50% chance of matching domains. Of that 20% might be valid. Leaves 80% uncertainty.

Comment: We prefer to see a [mcve] in the question so that we can clearly differentiate correct answers from incorrect answers.

Comment: To determine whether a domain is valid you essentially have to query a registrar database, and I'm not sure all TLDs offer that information freely. It all feels too ambitious to be done with just a single regular expression. What is your ultimate goal? Is single-regex a real constraint or just your attempt?

Comment: I would just like to extract all potential domains and ipv4 addresses from the string. It doesn't matter whether the domain exists, it simply should match the pattern